# A vectorized alternative to rep(`each=`) in R

Tags: r, function, loops, vectorization, mapply

I get a warning message in `rep()` that says `each=` argument is not vectorized.

Is there a vectorized alternative to `rep()` perhaps in `tidyverse()` or other base R alternative?

```
n_study <- 5
n_per_study_rows <- c(3,5,3,3,2)
rep(1:n_study, each=n_per_study_rows)

Warning message: first element used of 'each' argument
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `times` argument, not the `each` argument:

```r
n_study <- 5
n_per_study_rows <- c(3,5,3,3,2)
rep(1:n_study, times=n_per_study_rows)
#>  [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me from the question whether you actually wanted the `each` or `times` version of `rep`. To use the `each` version, you can use `rep` inside `sapply`:

```r
unlist(sapply(n_per_study_rows, function(x) rep(1:n_study, each = x)))
#>  [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 1 1
#> [35] 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4
```